# Show that $M \setminus f^{-1}(c)$ is disconnected if $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $c \in (\min f(M), \max f(M))$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

Let $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Prove that if $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is strictly between minimum and maximum of $f$ in $M$ then $M \setminus f^{-1}(c)$ is disconnected.

---

Can someone please check my proof?

Suppose that $M \setminus f^{-1}(c)$ is connected and define $g:=f|_{M \setminus f^{-1}(c)}$.

We know that $g$ is continuous, therefore the image of $g$ is also connected. Since the image of $g$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and connected sets of reals are intervals, the image of $g$ is an interval. That interval contains $\min f(M)$ and $\max f(M)$ but does not contains $c$ since $f^{-1}(c)$ is not in the domain of $g$, but $\min f(M) < c < \max f(M)$, which implies that the image of $g$ is not connected.

That's contradiction, because image of $g$ must be connected since $g$ is continuous and its domain is connected... therefore our assumption is impossible, which implies that $M \setminus f^{-1}(c)$ is disconnected.

---

Comments and critics are highly appreciated.

Comment: It’s perfect 

Comment: @FedericoFallucca thank you!!

Comment: Here is a more elementary way: We have$$M \setminus f^{-1}[\{c\}] = f^{-1}[\Bbb R \setminus \{c\}] = f^{-1}[(-\infty,c)] \cup f^{-1}[(c,\infty)],$$ and $f^{-1}[(-\infty,c)]$, $f^{-1}[(c,\infty)]$ are both non-empty because $c$ is strictly between $\min f[M]$ and $\max f[M]$.

Comment: Your idea is correct, but your proof has a defect: if $M$ is not compact, $\min f(M)$ and $\max f(M)$ in general do not exist. You can of course modify your proof, but it gets a bit more technical.

Comment: @azif00 This should be a official answer.

Comment: By the way, the question tacitly assumes that $\min f(M)$ and $\max f(M)$ exist. This is an unnecessary restriction. It suffices to asssume that $c$ is strictly between supremum and infimum of $f$ in $M$